# Fibonacci sequence algorithm in Javascript

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

I need to solve a Fibonacci question using JavaScript.

The function should have 3 parameters: 2 initial values and a final value.

The function should return the position of the final value in the Fibonacci series starting with the given initial values.

For example:

input: 2,5,19

output: 5
Because the series is 2,5,7,12,19 = 5

**how?**

Comment: 7 is not in the Fibonacci series. Neither is 12 or 19.

Comment: I know but that's the question

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Basically you want to compute how many "Fibonacci steps" are needed to get to the final value starting from the two initial values.

Comment: exactly !!! 
there is no code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function Fibonacci(f1, f2, val) {
    // print("fibanocci val:", f1);
    if(f1 == val) return 1;
    return Fibonacci(f2, f1+f2, val) + 1;
}

print(Fibonacci(2,5,19))
```

this should be what you asked.

EDIT: if input isn't always correct change this to avoid inf loop:

```
if(f1 >= val) return 1;
```

Comment: Ok it works but I did not quite understand how?

Comment: that's a recursion solution, Fibonacci F[N] = F[N-1] + F[N-2] - so if you have f1 and f2 init state and moves=1, you can use this function with next state, where next_f1 = f2 and next_f2 = f1+f2 and moves will increase with one. this is like this: return answer(next_state) + 1, when it reaches final destination if(f1 == val) you will stop calling rec. hope it helped...